# Merge tags networking and network

Tags: discussion, status-completed, synonym-request

Please correct me if I got something wrong -- but I can see no difference between the two. I'd suggest to merge [network](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/network) (10x) into [networking](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/networking) (78x) and make the former a synonym to the latter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Done!